# How to maximize a desktop application using TestStack.White after it is minimized

Tags: c#, desktop-application, ui-automation, white-framework

I have a code to minimize a desktop application using a minimize button at the top right button of the application.

But once it is minimized i have to do some operations with the browser and again switch back to desktop application. I face code issue here, where i need to click the application button in the task bar to maximize it.

Can anyone please help me on this or any other way to maximize the minimized application? i shouldn't close or reopen it, as some uploading will be in-progress.

Comment: Are you doing the uploading data from same application which you minized?

Comment: Yes..I have to do some functionality in web application for which uploading data has to be done through desktop application. While uploading data in .exe, I have to check the status in web application.

Comment: I don't clearly understand what you actually trying to achieve.

Comment: am working on a UI automation of web application. I need to switch between desktop application and Web application. Initially, will open a browser and perform some operation in web application, then will open a desktop application and do some process. minimize that and then switch back to browser but again I need to switch back to Desktop application and I dont know how to do this switching back to desktop.

Comment: What controls are you using, WebBrowser or selenium?

Comment: I'm using selenium for browser action and TestStack White with selenium for Desktop applications

Comment: So if white supports maximizing the application it will be done through the IWindowProvider since white is build on the UIA2 managed api. I would search their code looking to see if anything exposing the `IWindowProvider.SetVisualState`. I would go look but I am currently at work but I will attempt to check later.

Answer (score 2):

WinPattern is no longer public. Instead, you can use a DisplayState property.
E. g.:

```
wnd.DisplayState= DisplayState.Maximized;
```

Answer (score 1):

So after looking into how White exposes the [`WindowPattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.windowpattern(v=vs.110).aspx) I was able to find a public property on the [`Window`](https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/master/src/TestStack.White/UIItems/WindowItems/Window.cs) class called [`WinPattern`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.windowpattern(v=vs.110).aspx) which returns a [`WindowPattern`](https://github.com/TestStack/White/blob/master/src/TestStack.White/UIItems/WindowItems/Window.cs#L91). After getting the window pattern you should be able to call [`WindowPattern.SetWindowVisualState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.setwindowvisualstate(v=vs.110).aspx).

The link to the [`WindowPattern.SetWindowVisualState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.windowpattern.setwindowvisualstate(v=vs.110).aspx) has some good example code for how to use this pattern. I added the code that is most relevant with the use of White here since White handles getting the pattern for you.

```
///--------------------------------------------------------------------
/// <summary>
/// Calls the WindowPattern.SetVisualState() method for an associated 
/// automation element.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="windowPattern">
/// The WindowPattern control pattern obtained from
/// an automation element.
/// </param>
/// <param name="visualState">
/// The specified WindowVisualState enumeration value.
/// </param>
///--------------------------------------------------------------------
private void SetVisualState(WindowPattern windowPattern, 
    WindowVisualState visualState)
{
    try
    {
        if (windowPattern.Current.WindowInteractionState ==
            WindowInteractionState.ReadyForUserInteraction)
        {
            switch (visualState)
            {
                case WindowVisualState.Maximized:
                    // Confirm that the element can be maximized
                    if ((windowPattern.Current.CanMaximize) && 
                        !(windowPattern.Current.IsModal))
                    {
                        windowPattern.SetWindowVisualState(
                            WindowVisualState.Maximized);
                        // TODO: additional processing
                    }
                    break;
                case WindowVisualState.Minimized:
                    // Confirm that the element can be minimized
                    if ((windowPattern.Current.CanMinimize) &&
                        !(windowPattern.Current.IsModal))
                    {
                        windowPattern.SetWindowVisualState(
                        WindowVisualState.Minimized);
                        // TODO: additional processing
                    }
                    break;
                case WindowVisualState.Normal:
                    windowPattern.SetWindowVisualState(
                    WindowVisualState.Normal);
                    break;
                default:
                    windowPattern.SetWindowVisualState(
                    WindowVisualState.Normal);
                    // TODO: additional processing
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException)
    {
        // object is not able to perform the requested action
        return;
    }
}
```